# How do I force Eclipse to rebuild if files in another project change (any change)?

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, proguard

I've got an Eclipse (Galileo) project (called ProguardBuilder) that runs Proguard over a set of class files in other projects and produces a jar file.

I'd like to have the ProguardBuilder project get rebuilt any time any class file in the other projects changes.  AutoBuild doesn't do that; presumably it's smart enough to recognize and ignore any changes that don't affect anything externally visible.

My problem is that I don't care whether or not the change is visible, since I need to completely rebuild ProguardBuilder any time the class files it depends on change at all.

How do I tell Eclipse to do this sort of rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use an external builder. Check the documentation, because I've never done this. But the place to start is the "Builders" section of the project properties dialogue.

Comment: I think that's solving a different problem.  I've got an external builder right now, but it doesn't run on every change.

Comment: Have you made your project depend on the other one? You might need to put the external builder in the other project, so that when it changes then your builder will run.

Comment: Yes, ProguardBuilder depends on the other projects.  I want to centralize this building; adding a builder to n other projects is something I'd like to avoid.